# Using Android threads along with AudioRecorder

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm currently working on an Android project where the goal is to record audio and show a graph of the frequency-spectrum in real time. My design for this contains three threads:

- The UI-thread
- The recorder thread
- Several analysis threads

This diagram should show more or less how this should work

```
      Start
UI  |-•-------------•----------•------•----------•------•----------•--
       \           / \        /      / \        /      / \        /
        \         /   \      /      /   \      /      /   \      /
Ana      \       /     |----|      /     |----|      /     |----|       ...
          \     /                 /                 /
           \   /                 /                 /
Rec     |---•-•-----------------•-----------------•--------------------
              Notify           Notify           Notify
```

For clarity, let me explain how this works. At the beginning, the UI thread starts the recorder-thread. Using the [AudioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#setRecordPositionUpdateListener%28android.media.AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener%29)-method, a listener on the main thread is notified regularly. This listener starts a new thread for analysis. The results are returned to the main threads, which shows the results using [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home).

Note that the analysis is written low-level, so it doesn't take longer to analyse a frame than the length of the frame itself. This means that the analysis of a frame is able to take place before a new frame has to be analysed.

More precisely, I'm using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)s for all of this. The class in manages the AudioRecord is an AsyncTask, and the [OnRecordPositionUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener.html) calls publishProgress to go back to the main thread. In the onProgressUpdate method an object of the class AnalysisTask which extends AsyncTask is created. The results of the analysis is collected with the get()-method and shown in the UI-thread.

Sadly it doesn't work as smoothly as expected. A number of problems arise:

1) There is a stop-button on the GUI. Since the UI-thread is not blocked, the user should be able to use it in order to stop the process. However when it's pressed, the program appears to freeze, and crashes eventually (["application not responding"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)).

2) The logs tell me that there is a lot of time between the notification on the recorder-thread and the call to analyse on the UI thread. It even takes so long that another notification occurs inbetween. This causes the data to pile up, and eventually results in an OutOfMemory-error.

3) When the results are returned to the main-thread, there is a lot of time between the [redraw()](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.4.3/com/androidplot/Plot.html#redraw%28%29)-call and the actual appearance of the graph on the screen.

Given the fact that the processor is single-core, most of these problems can be explained by the scheduling of the threads, right? In that case, they are caused by the recorder thread being so busy that the UI thread is scheduled too late, thus causing a delay between a task arriving in the queue and it actually being executed.

Is there a way to solve this? Can I prevent the recorder thread to take all the CPU power, without losing frames or the regularity of the notification towards the UI thread? I tried `Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);` but without results.

Thanks!

Comment: "it doesn't take longer to analyse a frame than the length of the frame itself" Are you sure? And is it fast enough if you do the recording at the same time? It might just be that you lack processing power; there's nothing you can do about that except get a new phone or write the signal processing in renderscript and hope it's fast enough.

Comment: @toto2 I am fairly sure. I can tell from the logs which tell the difference in time between the start and the end of the analysis. It says around 700 ms for a 1 s frame.